# Binding Hex value to Color in XAML

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

I have objects stored in a database that I am displaying in a GridView. I am binding each of their properties from the database. The color property is stored as a Hex value.

I am trying to bind this hex value using a converter function as shown below and just returning Red every time for now.

It seems to be working but it eventually returns the following error:
The program '[5548] TranslatorService.Example.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code -1073741189 (0xc000027b).

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

The code-behind:

```
public class StringToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, String language)
    {
        return Colors.Red;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, String language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The XAML:

```
 <Grid.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ColorHex, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}" />
                    </Grid.Background>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

In my experience you need to assing a Brush, not a Color:

```
SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
mySolidColorBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0);
```

or

```
mySolidColorBrush.Color = Color.Red;
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update my code. I am doing that currently.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be resolved after recompiling.

Answer (score 0):

In your posted converter code, you are returning Color.Red, so no matter what `value` is, you'll get Red every time.